# Use Chunk Listener for Indicator Pattern

Tags: spring-batch, idempotent

I am trying to use Processor Indicator Pattern to make my job idempotent, i tried to use Write Listener, AfterWrite to update mongo document by setting a field Processed: true. However there were issues when there is a big number of chunks.

**MongoDB Item Reader(10000 Docs) ---chunk(1000)--> JDBC Batch Item Writer(Only 5000 are saved in table after Step's completion)**

The following Code is about The step:

```
@Bean
    public MongoItemReader<X> Reader() throws Exception {
        MongoItemReader<X> reader = new MongoItemReader<>();
        reader.setTemplate(mongoTemplate);
        reader.setCollection("MY_COLLECTION");
        reader.setTargetType(X.class);
        reader.setQuery("{PROCESSED: {$exists: false}}");
        reader.setSort(new HashMap<String, Sort.Direction>() {{
            put("_id", Sort.Direction.ASC);
        }});
        reader.afterPropertiesSet();
        return reader;
    }

    @Bean
    public XItemProcessor x_item_processor() {
        return new XItemProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public X_Item_Listener item_listener() {
        return new X_Item_Listener();
    }

    @Bean
    public X_Step_Listener step_listener() {
        return new X_Step_Listener();
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcBatchItemWriter<Y> YWriter() {
        JdbcBatchItemWriter<Y> Y_Writer = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<>();
        Y_Writer.setDataSource(dataSource);
        Y_Writer.setAssertUpdates(true);
        Y_Writer.setItemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<>());
        Y_Writer.setSql("INSERT INTO Y (Y1,Y2,Y3,Y4) VALUES (:y1, :y2, :y3, :y4)");
        Y_Writer.afterPropertiesSet();
        return Y_Writer;
    }


    @Bean
    public Step XY_Step() throws Exception {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("XY")
                .<X, Y>chunk(1000)
                .reader(Reader())
                .processor(x_item_processor())
                .writer(YWriter())
                .faultTolerant()
                .skipLimit(Integer.MAX_VALUE)
                .skip(Exception.class)
                .listener((ItemProcessListener<? super X, ? super Y>) item_listener())
                .listener(step_listener())
                .build();
    }
```

Here a snippet of code used in After Write Listener for updating mongo Document.

```
@Autowired
private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void afterWrite(List<? extends Y> items) {
    BulkOperations ops=mongoTemplate.bulkOps(BulkOperations.BulkMode.UNORDERED,"MY_COLLECTION");
    for (Y item : items) {
        Update update = new Update().set("PROCESSED", true);
        ops.updateOne(new Query(Criteria.where("_id").is(item.getID())), update);
    }
    ops.execute();
}
```

Comment: `However there were issues when there is a big number of chunks.`: Before going the listener route, what are these issues with a big number of chunks?

Comment: For example if i have collection that contains 10000 documents, and i set chunk commit interval at 1000, only 5000 out of 10000 will be commited in db. The rest will be discarded despite the fact that all the 10000 documents will be updated and the flag of processed will be set. commenting the code shown above or setting the chunk number at 10000 will solve the problem.

Comment: `if i have collection that contains 10000 documents, and i set chunk commit interval at 1000, only 5000 out of 10000 will be commited in db`: Why is that? With a chunk size of 1000, only 1000 should be committed at a time, and their processed flag should be set to true as part of that transaction if it is updated in the writer (no need for a listener with a new transaction). The initial issue is not clear from what you shared, it would be more efficient to help you if you provide a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces it.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine, Sorry for the unclear example. Full code of Step is provided now

Comment: Thanks for the update. I still don't see why only 5000 items are written and not 10000. With chunkSize=1000, you should have 10 transactions and all the 10000 items should be persisted. That said, you are updating the processed flag in a separate transaction, which could go out of sync if one of the transactions fails. You need a composite writer with one that writes to the relational database, and one that updates the processed flag in mongo. Both writers should be executed in the same transaction. For this, you need a JtaTransactionManager that coordinates both transactions managers.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine i want to know if it is possible to write a custom item writer that write to both databases at the same time.

Comment: Yes, that's possible. Spring Batch already provides a `CompositeItemWriter`, but if it does not fit your need, you can write a custom one and use it in your step.